# What is the external force acting on a hanged bob by hand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

Consider one end of a massless spring $k$ is stationary fixed at a roof. A bob of  mass $m$ is attached to the other end of the spring. At $t=T$ the spring gets elongated $mg/k$ and for $t\geq T$ the bob is stationary.

This scenario will not possible if we freely release the bob without external force $f(x,t)$.

The equation of motion satisfies the following differential equation.
$$
mg-kx-f(x,t)= m\frac{\textrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}
$$
The constraints are
\begin{align}
x(0) &=0\\
\dot{x}(0) &=0\\
x(t\geq T) &=\frac{mg}{k}\\ 
\dot{x}(t\geq T)&=0
\end{align}

What is $f(x,t)$? Assume that $T$ is finite.

Note: I ask this question because I wonder how to interpret what most people say "The bob is gently released ...". I want to have more rigorous and mathematical interpretation.

Comment: It is not a homework. But for my own learning.

Comment: This might help. It considers that example. [Green's Function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqg8L41u4Yg)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be non-unique?

It seems to me that there could be a number of ways to arrest the mass in space to meet your conditions.

I suppose you could put a constraint on it though. The work done by $f$ must balance the work done by the spring and weight.

Comment: Yes. It might be non-unique. If you don't mind, please make your own assumption.

Comment: Okay, here's the simplest one I can think of: At $t = T^-$ ($x = \frac{mg}{k}^-$), $f$ is of a shock form. It can be modeled with a Dirac delta function and is such that, when integrated, the impulse kills entirely the momentum of the bob. You can imagine a hammer whacking the bob when it reaches the equilibrium position.

Comment: Could you please write your derivation to make it much clearer? But if you hit the bob at the equilibrium then "We release the bob gently..."  does not make sense any more. :-)